# How to get Records in Specific date range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, date

My query does not work. I'm using codeigniter. I want to filter the list of fetch those records on the basis of date range.

Here is My controller:

```
public function filter($type){
  $fromdt = date("Y-d-m",strtotime($this->input->post("from")));
  $todt = date("Y-d-m",strtotime($this->input->post("to")));
  $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
  $this->load->model("mymodel");    
  print_r($this->mymodel->filterdata($fromdt,$todt,$session_data['id'])); 
}
```

Here is my in Model:

```
public function filterdata($from,$to,$userid){
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT table1.id,table1.quest,table1.post_id,table1.quote_id,table2.in_dairy FROM table1,table2 
  WHERE table2.quote_id = table1.id AND table2.reader_id='$userid' 
  AND table1.in_dairy='yes' AND table2.dairy_dt>='$from' AND 
  table2.dairy_dt<='$to'");
  return $query->result();
}
```

Note: MY dairy_dt field is TYPE OF DATE in Mysql. I don't know why it shows an empty result..

Comment: how $fromdt and $todt looks like after u convert them to Y-m-d ?

Comment: You've written `table12.quote_id` when there is no table12. Also you're doing `AND table2.dairy_dt>='$from' AND 
  table1.dairy_dt<='$to'`. These should be from the same table

Comment: thats my writing mistake.See the latest edits

Answer (score 0):

Try after Update your function to

```
public function filter($type){
   $fromdt = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->input->post("from")));
   $todt = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->input->post("to")));
   $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
   $this->load->model("mymodel");    
   print_r($this->mymodel->filterdata($fromdt,$todt,$session_data['id'])); 
}
```

The MySql date format is like: ***Y-m-d***

Comment: it still returns empty array

Comment: Can you provide your schema, sample data? are you getting data if you remove the date from condition do you get data?

Comment: yes i got the data if i remove the date from condition

Comment: My **wild** guess would be you are passing date values in other then **"Y-m-d"** format. can you give me the exact date value you are submitting?

Answer (score 0):

Why you return $query->result() if you are not assigning the query you made? I mean,

```
$this->db->query("SELECT table1.....
return $query->result();
```

where is the $query value?, you should do

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT table1.....
return $query->result();
```